# How to get the coordinates of where on the model the user clicked in model-viewer

Tags: reactjs, model-viewer

I have just started using model-viewer and it fits my use case perfectly. However when I visited the section for annotation no where could I find how can I add annotations dynamically. I want my users to have the ability to add annotations by themselves.

Model-Viewer: https://modelviewer.dev/
Docs: https://modelviewer.dev/docs/

Comment: setup an array holding config objects for your annotations (which a user can add/remove from, from the UI),  and then map them within the model-viewer tags. Perhaps setup a codesandbox with the mode-viewer already configured within the context you wish to use it. There we can help a little easier without having to do the leg work

Comment: https://modelviewer.dev/examples/annotations/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the input. I just need to know how I can obtain a data-position and data-normal values when a user clicks on the model. I already know how I can show annotations. Unfortunately I am unable to get the position value to show it at the right place

Comment: Are you looking to transform a client x and y hit position, to a target on the model? Take a look at this example: https://modelviewer.dev/examples/stagingandcameras/#panning

it uses positionAndNormalFromPoint(clientX, clientY) function. Try add an onclick event, which grabs the mouse pointer position and passes it to this function. It returns data-position and data-normal attributes, which you should be able to use to configure those attributes on an annotation

Comment: I had tried that but for some reason, it just didn't work. It kept returning null for me. Here is the code:


const getCord = async (event) => {
    console.log(event.screenX, event.screenY)
    const modelViewer = document.querySelector('#model-viewer')
    const vals = modelViewer.positionAndNormalFromPoint(
      event.screenX,
      event.screenY
    )

    console.log(vals)
  }

Comment: if you log event.screenX, do you actually get a value? usually its clientX

Comment: I did get a value. Here is the codeSandbox link:


https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-proskuriakova-zyg8o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ok. I got it to work. ClientX and Y does give me what I want. Thanks, man. I appreciate your help. +1

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-tree-d41cr?file=/src/App.js here is some hotspotting